# getting $x$ and $y$ by solving simultaneously

Tags: geometry

I need some help.  My question is: suppose you are given the equations of two lines in form of $y=mx+c$, and then you are told they intersect at point $P$ and they ask you to find the coordinates of point $P$. Can you rearrange the equations as $ax+by=c$ and then solve them simultaneously to get values of $x$ and $y$ which will be your coordinate?

Comment: do you mean $$y=mx+c$$ and $$ax+by=c$$?

Comment: yeah I'm New here for I really don't know how to ask questions but I meant that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a choice about how to solve such equations. In fact you have several choices. What you describe is one such choice.

If you have two lines described by equations in the form
\begin{align}
a_1 x + b_1 y &= c_1 \\
a_2 x + b_2 y &= c_2, \\
\end{align}
and you solve these equations simultaneously,
the solution $(x,y)$ is the point of intersection of the two lines.

This method is just as legitimate when you were given the equations originally in the form $y=mx+c$ and you converted them into the form
$ax+by=c,$
as it is when you were originally given the equations in the form $ax+by=c.$
As long as you convert the forms of the equations accurately
(for example, you write $-3$ and not $3$ when you should write $-3$)
then the equations represent the same lines and their simultaneous solution represents the same point of intersection.

Comment: thanks alot actually I was just confirming if I did the right thing in my pure maths exam

Comment: Based on what you have described, your method was correct. It may not have been the _simplest_ method, but it was a good one.

Comment: yayyy thanks hope I pass the exam because when my friends were discussing answers it was totally different from what I got

Comment: and what's the simplest method to get the x and y values

Comment: If the equations of your two lines are $y = m_1 x + c_1$ and $y = m_2 x + c_2,$ you can write $m_1 x + c_1 = m_2 x + c_2,$ solve for $x,$ then use that value of $x$ in one of the original equations to find $y.$ Your method is more generally useful, however, partly because it can deal with vertical lines but mostly because it generalizes to objects in higher-dimensional spaces, not just lines in a plane.

Comment: i see thanks alot it really reduces my stress over my pure math exam

Answer (score 0):

if so we get $$ax+b(mx+c)=c$$ thus we have $$x(a+bm)=c-bc$$ solving for $x$ we get
$$x=\frac{c-bc}{a+nbm}$$ if $$a+bm\ne 0$$
and for $y$ we obtain $$y=\frac{m(c-bc)}{a+bm}+c$$
you can also write
$$y-mx=c$$
$$by+ax=c$$ 
multiplying the first equation by $$-b\ne 0$$ then we have
$$-by+bmx=-bc$$
$$by+ax=c$$
adding both equation we obtain
$$ax+bmx=c-bc$$
for further see my solution above.

Comment: actually when I said to put $$y=mx+c$$ into $$ax+by=c$$ I meant that u rearrange the equation for example if it was y=2x+3 then we rearrange the equation so it becomes 2x-y=-3 so we do this for both equations and solve simultaneously